# Разбить значение адреса в столбце и взять почтовый индекс и город в отдельные стоблцы

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas

коллеги! Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой разделения столбцов.
Имеется следующий датафрейм:

```
Регистрационный номер      Адрес местонахождения
  1140280002235            453405, Башкортостан респ, Давлекановский район, 
                           г. Давлеканово, ул. Заводская, д. 1, 
  1147746032312            127486, г. Москва, ул. Дегунинская, 
                           д. 1 корп. 2 этаж 2 ком. 7
  1140280002312            450064, Башкортостан респ, г. Уфа, 
                           ул. Интернациональная, д. 29,116 
                           пом. 1-4,7,8,8А,30,30А,31-40,40А
```

Необходимо адрес местонахождения разделить на 2 отдельных столбца Zip_code, где будут значения почтового индекса, City, где будет указан город, которые обозначен после г.

попытался вытащить сперва потчовый индекс, но выдает ошибку cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. Попытался убрать Na но все равно ошибка не исчезла, по городам не могу подобрать регулярное выражение :(

```
pat = r'\d{6}'
df_findata['zip_code'] = df_findata[df_findata['Адрес (место нахождения)'].str.extract(pat)]
```

Comment: Может, `df_findata['zip_code'] = df_findata['Адрес местонахождения'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{6})\b').fillna('')`?

Comment: Спасибо, с индексом проблема решилась, а не знаете как город вычленить через регулярку?

Comment: Если вы сможете определить контекст, можно попытаться написать такое выражение.

Comment: я обратил внимание, что город идет после 'г.' и до запятой, но я регулярках я не силен к сожалению

Comment: `df_findata['city_name'] = df_findata['Адрес местонахождения'].str.extract(r'\bг\.\s*([^,]+)')`?

Comment: Wiktor, огромное спасибо! все работает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
df_findata['zip_code'] = df_findata['Адрес местонахождения'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{6})\b')
df_findata['city_name'] = df_findata['Адрес местонахождения'].str.extract(r'\bг\.\s*([^,]+)')
```

Индекс находится с помощью `\b(\d{6})\b` (шесть цифр как целое слово), а город — с помощью `\bг\.\s*([^,]+)`: целое слово `г.`, 0 и более пробельных символов, а затем 1 и более символов, отличных от запятой.

См. [демо №1](https://regex101.com/r/VVngYf/1) и [демо №2](https://regex101.com/r/VVngYf/2).

Обратите внимание на круглые скобки в шаблонах: `str.extract` возвращает подстроку, найденную именно этой частью шаблона.